# function not included, why?

Tags: php, function, include

what is wrong with my code??? :

```
function my_function()
{
$states = array('schwarz', 'rot', 'blau');

$path = '';

foreach ($states as $state) {
    $testPath = sprintf('transactions/Ordner/%s.png', $state);

    if (file_exists($testPath)) {
      $path = $testPath;
      echo $path;
    }
    else {
      $defaultPath = "inventory_images/8.jpg";
      echo $defaultPath;
    }
}
}


$imagesPerLine = array(1=>2, 2=>3); $default = 4;
$lines = array(1, 2, 3);
$html="";
foreach ($lines as $line) {
if (!isset($imagesPerLine[$line])) {
  $imagesPerLine[$line] = $default;
}
$html.= "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $imagesPerLine[$line]; $i++) {
  $html.=sprintf("<td>%s</td>\n", my_function());
}
$html.="</tr>\n";

}
echo $html;
```

i thought, i included my_function() into the "td-tag", but it doesnt work, because none of my variables($path and $defaultPath) is echoed.
i cant find my mistake, could you help me?...greetings

Comment: Don't `echo`, instead `return` the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `return` instead of `echo`.

To simplify, let's change your code to this:

```
$text = my_function();
$html = sprintf("<td>%s</td>\n",$text);
```

This is, for all practical purposes, identical to your original code.

Your `my_function()` call contains `echo` statements. These are evaluated and the output is sent. The function itself has no `return` statement, therefore your code effectively becomes:

```
echo "something";
$text = null;
$html = sprintf("<td>%s</td>",$text);
```

Using `return` instead makes your code work as expected.

Comment: thanks :) great works